# can not upload the images

Tags: python, django

why I can not upload the images??
The urls.py: 
see the

> url(r'^things,,,

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from collection import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,RedirectView,)
from collection.backends import MyRegistrationView
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from collection.sitemap import (
    ThingSitemap,
    StaticSitemap,
    HomepageSitemap,
)
sitemaps = {
    'things': ThingSitemap,
    'static': StaticSitemap,
    'homepage': HomepageSitemap,
}
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    password_reset,
    password_reset_done,
    password_reset_confirm,
    password_reset_complete,
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html'),name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/$',views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^things/$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='browse', permanent=True)),
    url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.thing_detail,name='thing_detail'),
    url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$', views.edit_thing,name='edit_thing'),
    url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/images/$', views.edit_thing_uploads,name='edit_thing_uploads'),
    url(r'^browse/$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='browse', permanent=True)),
    url(r'^browse/name/$',views.browse_by_name, name='browse'),
    url(r'^browse/name/(?P<initial>[-\w]+)/$',views.browse_by_name, name='browse_by_name'),
    url(r'^accounts/password/reset/$', password_reset,{'template_name':'registration/password_reset_form.html'},name="password_reset"),
    url(r'^accounts/password/reset/done/$', password_reset_done,{'template_name':'registration/password_reset_done.html'},name="password_reset_done"),
    url(r'^accounts/password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', password_reset_confirm,{'template_name':'registration/password_reset_confirm.html'},name="password_reset_confirm"),
    url(r'^accounts/password/done/$', password_reset_complete,{'template_name':'registration/password_reset_complete.html'},name="password_reset_complete"),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$',MyRegistrationView.as_view(),name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/create_thing/$',views.create_thing,name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps':sitemaps},name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),


]

from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
    ]
```

the views.py:
See the `def edit_thing_uploads`

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import Http404
from collection.forms import ThingForm,ContactForm,ThingUploadForm
from collection.models import Thing,Upload
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template import Context


def index(request):
    things = Thing.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'things':things,
        })


def thing_detail(request, slug):
    thing = Thing.objects.get(slug=slug)
    social_accounts = thing.social_accounts.all()
    uploads = thing.uploads.all()
    return render(request, 'things/thing_detail.html',{
        'thing':thing,
        'social_accounts': social_accounts,
        'uploads': uploads,
        })

@login_required
def edit_thing(request, slug):
    thing = Thing.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if thing.user != request.user:
        raise Http404

    form_class = ThingForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST, instance=thing)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=thing)

    return render(request, 'things/edit_thing.html',{'thing':thing,'form':form,})

@login_required
def edit_thing_uploads(request, slug):
    thing = Thing.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if thing.user != request.user:
        raise Http404

    form_class = ThingUploadForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES, instance=thing)
        if form.is_valid():
            Upload.objects.create(
                image=form.cleaned_data['image'],
                thing=thing,
            )
            return redirect('edit_thing_uploads', slug=thing.slug)

    else:
        form = form_class(instance=thing)
    uploads = thing.uploads.all()

    return render(request, 'things/edit_thing_uploads.html', {
        'thing': thing,
        'form': form,
        'uploads': uploads,
    })

def create_thing(request):
    form_class = ThingForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            thing = form.save(commit=False)
            thing.user = request.user
            thing.slug = slugify(thing.name)
            thing.save()

            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)

    else:
        form = form_class()

    return render(request, 'things/create_thing.html', {'form':form,})

def browse_by_name(request, initial=None):
    if initial:
        things = Thing.objects.filter(name__istartswith=initial)
        things = things.order_by('name')
    else:
        things = Thing.objects.all().order_by('name')

    return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'things':things,'initial':initial,})


def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
            contact_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
            form_content = form.cleaned_data['content']

            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')

            context = Context({
                'contact_name':contact_name,
                'contact_email':contact_email,
                'form_content':form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                'New contact form submission',content,
                'Your website <hi@weddinglovely.com>',['fnt437@gmail.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To':contact_email }
            )
            email.send()
            return redirect('contact')

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form_class, })
```

The forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ThingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = ('name','description',)

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Your name:"
        self.fields['contact_email'].label = "Your email:"
        self.fields['content'].label = "What do you want to say?"

class ThingUploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('image',)
```

the edit_thing.html:

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Edit {{ thing.name }} - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Edit "{{ thing.name }}"</h1>

<a href="{% url 'edit_thing_uploads' slug=thing.slug %}">Edit images</a>

<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

the edit_thing_uploads.html:

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Edit {{ thing.name }}'s Images - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Edit {{ thing.name }}'s Images</h1>

<h2>Uploaded images</h2>
{% for upload in uploads %}
<img src="{{ uploads.image.url }}" alt="" />
  {% endfor %}

<h2>Uploads a new image</h2>
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form\-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

the diirectory tree:
[image]

when I click in http://127.0.0.1:8000/things/another-things/edit/ is ok
[image]

however when I click the Edit images link to submit upload images it said no file has been choice?? I can not upload the images[image]

Comment: Have you restarted the server since adding the template?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the file permissions of

> edit_thing_uploads.html

, make sure the file is accessible. because the path has been correct. and Django can't see it.

Comment: thanks,,,I got to know why,,it *.html but in my Mac's finder it does not shows it is *.html file,,,that is stange?? however I delete it and recreate the same file it can work,,,but I still can not upload the image,,but it can show the page ok

Comment: I change the question to can not upload images

Answer (score 0):

I got to know why ,,because I typos `<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> ---> <form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form\-data">`   in edit_thing_uploads.html